# Faster XLSX Writer for R?

Tags: r

I am currently using OpenXLSX for appending new worksheets to an existing XLSX file, but it is quite slow at times because it has to read in the whole existing XLSX in order to append, and that can take minutes. Is there anything faster for appending worksheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) package in R. Specifically the write method for xlsx2 is designed for faster implementation.